# Why is my UIWebView showing lots of HTML instead of the local file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have a "download manager" integrated into my iPhone App which allows the user to save a webpage online to their documents folder on their device to view offline and locally. This works perfectly, except the files show with lots of HTML code rather than what they should look like.

Here's the UITableView with files: http://cl.ly/3D2g0o3C3a302J243D3v
Here's the UIWebView with the HTML in it instead of the usual webpage: http://cl.ly/2s1h3H3D1c1t3y1J2G0W

I'm loading my UIWebView like this (looks all fine?):

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:documentsDirectory]; 
NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to rectify this?

Comment: make a nslog for url and check that are you getting proper url.

Comment: OK, I've put "NSLog(@"URL Being Loaded: %@", url);" and it's returning "URL Being Loaded: file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/1186A8C1-54AA-45E2-8578-713E63E23874/Documents/network_file.phtml" - this is correct :)

Comment: Does the same problem occur if you load the document contents into an NSString and then use UIWebView's loadHTMLString:baseURL: ?

Comment: the problem is with your url .This is not a proper url.If you try to open it on web .It wont be.You need to check where you are setting your url.

Comment: Wekwa, not tried that yet... Gypsa, It's working perfectly on Safari though :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this line of code my friend,

```
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

and here is a code that i use before:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appSettingsPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];
```

now, you have the file path in your document directory.
then:

```
[webview loadHTMLString:SiteString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:appSettingsPath]];
```

Comment: You've not read what I'm trying to do, I need to retrieve the file from my documents directory in a UITableView...

Comment: i know that my friend. Save the html file in your document directory and use the `NSBundle` to retrieve the file.

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't always going to be a HTML file, sometimes a .png, .txt or .doc?

Comment: well, that a little bit complex than i though, anyway, you have to check for that you have, if you have an html, then load the `UIWebView`, if you have a *.png then you have to load a `UIImageView`, and so on for every type you save.